# Is there a mythological basis for the glass-eyed men in Gunnerkrigg Court?

Tags: fantasy-genre, webcomics, mythology, gunnerkrigg-court

Gunnerkrigg Court is a brilliant amalgam of fantasy and mythology, and many of the characters and story elements come straight out of myths. While Coyote himself is obviously the Native American trickster-hero, I can't find any mythology related to the GC story of his creation of the glass-eyed men. Does that plot element come out of any particular legend, or is it solely within the GC universe?

Comment: A reference to what they are might help: http://gunnerkrigg.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_People

Comment: Also: http://www.gunnerkrigg.com/archive_page.php?comicID=977

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Maidu creation myth](http://www.firstpeople.us/FP-Html-Legends/TheCreation-Maidu.html) contains the following passage, explaining how Coyote tried to make people but laughed, therefore creating the [glassy-eyed people that we know as Shadow People in Gunnerkrigg Court](http://gunnerkrigg.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_People) (thanks to @Brandan Long for the Gunnerkrigg ref):

> When Coyote had seen the two people, he asked Earth-Initiate how he
>   had made them. When he was told, he thought, "That is not difficult.
>   I'll do it myself." He did just as Earth-Initiate had told him, but
>   could not help laughing, when, early in the morning, the woman poked
>   him in the ribs.
>
> As a result of his failing to keep still, the people were glass-eyed.
>   Earth- Initiate said, "I told you not to laugh," but Coyote declared
>   he had not. This was the first lie.